# SAS MYSQL libname connection issue

Tags: mysql, sas

Can anyone help with the following?

```
5    LIBNAME test1 mysql server='blah.blah.com' user='blah' password=XXXXXX;

ERROR: The SAS/ACCESS Interface to MYSQL cannot be loaded. The libmysql code appendage could not be
       loaded.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```

Am using SAS 9.3, and downloaded the latest MySQL client today (v5.2.47).

As per [Usage Note 37512](http://support.sas.com/kb/37/512.html) I am **not** using the following statement either in my code, nor in the sasv9.cfg file:

```
options set=sasmyl mywin417;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a pointer to the MySQL library in your path variable?

```
data _null_;
format x $10000.;
x=sysget('path');
put x=;
run;
```

If a path to the MYSQL location is not in the list above, there are two options:

1 - update the path variable to point at the correct location (restart required): http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#0

2 - presuming the correct location does not exist, you may not have the software correctly installed.  Try installing from this location:  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Another issue might be with the connector.  This can be downloaded from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/.  A further step is to copy the libmysql.dll file from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2 to C:\Windows\System32...

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is that your SAS installation is not licenced for SAS/Access Interface to MYSQL.

Comment: Good guess but I don't think so. "Cannot be loaded" suggested it is installed.  If it was not installed, the message would say "cannot be found".

Answer (score 0):

Solved the same problem just adding to path not bin, but lib directory. Also in this dir was libmysql.dll file

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem as well. I just put the libmysql.dll file into the System32 folder and it worked. Also could try the SysWOW64 if System32 does not help.